# User defined validators in Django fields

Tags: python, django

Django lets you define validators of a model field like this:

```
field = models.CharField(..,validators=[],..)
```

If I were to allow users to attach validators to a field, what would be the best way?

For instance, let's say the user would like to apply a RegexValidator in this field where the regex parameter is defined by them. How would I achive that behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about a comma-separated list of names in a separate field and a wrapper property, e.g.:

```
import django.core.validators as validator_module

# Build a map of available validators.  This code is not foolproof
# and might be better as a static dict, but it gives the idea.
validator_map = {}
for name, obj in validator_module.__dict__.items():
    if name.startswith('validate') pr name.endswith('Validator'):
        validator_map[name] = obj

class MyModel(Model):
    value = CharField()
    value_validators = TextField()

    def set_value(self, value):
        'Run validators and store the value'
        vnames = self.value_validators.split(',')
        for vname in vnames:
            validator = validator_map[vname]
            validator(value)
        self.value = value
```

Comment: thanks, it could work! how can i pass the arguments to the validators? for instance, if it's a MinLengthValidator, i'd need to pass the minimum value also against which the actual value is being compared. No?

Comment: i guess i'd have to take tuples as inputs from the user.